# stopwords and synonyms in nutch

Tags: nutch

is there is any option to configure stop words and synonyms in nutch crawler

```
synonyms 

gov-->government
```

some thing similar to this`

Answer (score 0):

It's no very easy but if you are going to be ready of writing your own Indexer plugin I think yes.